# Replacing a restarting sequence in a dataframe with the group number of the sequence

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, sequence

I have a sequence in `df$V1` that starts at some number and increases. At some point, it drops, indicating that observations for a new group have started. I want to replace `V1` (or create a new column) with the group number. What are some ways to do this? I've tried various `dplyr` tricks to no avail, and searched here and elsewhere and have not found a similar problem. *Wondering if there's a slick dplyr way to do this.* Thank you for any insights.

The data frame has about 350 rows. Here is a subset:

```
> df
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1   1  5  9  1  2 14
2   2  5 10  1  3  9
3   3  5 11  1  4  4
4   4  5 15  1  5  7
5   5  5 18  1  6 14
6   6  5 22  1  7  6
27  1  5  9  1  2 14
28 21  9 10  2  3  4
29 22  9 11  2  4  6
30 23  9 15  2  5  1
31 24  9 18  2  6  7
32 25  9 22  2  7 14
33 26  9 24  2  8  6
34 27  9 25  2  9  7
35 28  9 26  2 10  6
```

And I want it to look like this (or with `group` as an added column in the `new.df`):

```
> new.df
   group V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
1      1  5  9  1  2 14
2      1  5 10  1  3  9
3      1  5 11  1  4  4
4      1  5 15  1  5  7
5      1  5 18  1  6 14
6      1  5 22  1  7  6
27     2  5  9  1  2 14
28     2  9 10  2  3  4
29     2  9 11  2  4  6
30     2  9 15  2  5  1
31     2  9 18  2  6  7
32     2  9 22  2  7 14
33     2  9 24  2  8  6
34     2  9 25  2  9  7
35     2  9 26  2 10  6
```

Here's the initial data frame to load into your R session:

```
df <- read.table(header=TRUE, text="
   V1 V2 V3 V4 V5 V6
  1  5  9  1  2 14
  2  5 10  1  3  9
  3  5 11  1  4  4
  4  5 15  1  5  7
  5  5 18  1  6 14
  6  5 22  1  7  6
  1  5  9  1  2 14
 21  9 10  2  3  4
 22  9 11  2  4  6
 23  9 15  2  5  1
 24  9 18  2  6  7
 25  9 22  2  7 14
 26  9 24  2  8  6
 27  9 25  2  9  7
 28  9 26  2 10  6
")
```

Comment: `cumsum(c(1, sign(diff(df$V1)) < 0))` seems to work.

Comment: Or: `c(1, cumsum(diff(df$V1) < 0) + 1)`

Comment: V4 gets wonky farther down in the dataset... I did try that at first :) Thanks though.

Comment: Using the other comments, what about `df %>%
    mutate(
        d = sign(V1 - lag(V1) < 0),
        d = ifelse(is.na(d), 0, d),
        group = 1 + cumsum(d)
    )` in a dplyr chain? What do you mean with "wonky V4"? And how is V4 relevant for the grouping?